# Create Element Doesn't work in jquery 1.8.3

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I Have used jquery 1.8.3 to Dynamically Create the Element. But It doesn't working on this. but It's working on 1.3.2 version. Below is My Jquery Code Which I Have used for that.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

        if(counter>10){
                alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
             .attr("id", 'CallBackDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Call Back Date Time #'+ counter + ': </label>'+
              '<div class="controls"><input type="text" name="callback' + counter + 
              '" id="callback' + counter + '" value="" ></div>');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#control-group");


        counter++;
         });

         $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
              alert("No more textbox to remove");
              return false;
           }   

        counter--;

            $("#CallBackDiv" + counter).remove();

         });

         $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
          msg += "\n CallBack #" + i + " : " + $('#callback' + i).val();
        }
              alert(msg);
         });
      });
```

---

```
<div id='control-group'>
    <div id="CallBackDiv1">
<label class="control-label" for="input01">
Call Back Date Time #1:</label><div class="controls">
<input type='textbox' id='callback1' ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='+' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='-' id='removeButton'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can dynamically create elements like this:

```
// Create a new div
var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'CallBackDiv' + counter
});    

// Append the new element to the DOM
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#control-group");

// You can check the console for the 'newTextBoxDiv' id
console.log(newTextBoxDiv.attr('id'));

// Then call the after part
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('...');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3psvM/)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the way you are creating the `div`. The problem with your code is your use of **jQuery's** `after()` function. Calling `after()` on a newly created element will return `null`, which you are then calling the `html()` method on. I suggest you read up on how to use the `after()` function -> http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

why dont you do it in plain js

```
var newTextBoxDiv = document.createElement('div');
newTextBoxDiv.setAttribute("id", 'CallBackDiv' + counter);
```